# UIViewController in iOS app launch screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, launch-screen

Is it possible to add a view controller to `launch screen` in `iOS`? 
if yes How could i do that?

I have dragged a `UIViewController` to the `LaunchScreen.xib` file its run correctly, but when I changed the class for the view controller in the `LaunchScreen.xib` from "identity inspector" from `UIViewController` to `myLaunchScreenViewControllerName`
I faced this error

> Illegal Configuration : Launch screen may not use instance of myLaunchScreenViewControllerName

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Launch screen is is not a fully customizable view controller. You cannot specify a custom class name in the storyboard and expect the system to give you the option to execute code at this stage by calling `viewDidLoad`. Remember, the app hasn’t launched yet